# How do you create HVM AMI images on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

How do you create HVM AMI images on EC2?

I've searched a bit, it seems I am only able to create a paravirtualization AMI image, which means it cannot be applied on the HVM-based instances.

FYI, I'm using spot-instances only.

Answer (score 0):

The instance you are taking the AMI of has to be hvm.  In the case it is a PV instance, you must first turn it into an HVM, which essentially means starting from scratch on the build of the instance (there is a way to convert it, but I was unsuccessful at it: [see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/439976/create-an-aws-hvm-linux-ami-from-an-existing-paravirtual-linux-ami?rq=1)).  Then once you have an HVM image, you should be able to launch an hvm instance.