# How to convert CENTOS5 PV AMI to HVM one?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I asked to migrate existing CENTOS5-basedEC2  server to the new T2 instance.
I created AMI, but it can't be launched as T2 instance because T2 supports only HVM virtualization. 
There are few manuals for converting AMI from  PV to HVM (http://www.nixhat.com/2014/01/migrate-aws-pv-to-hvm-instance/, for example); but in order to do it, I need "to implant" HVM kernel into my server. But there is no CENTOS5 HVM AMIs!
Is there any workaround?

May I use just vanilla CENTOS5 kernel - AFAIK, PV uses modified kernel, not sure about HVM?

TIA,
Vitaly

Comment: How about saving the volume of your EC2 instance, implanting that volume on the new instance and setting grub to boot from the newly attached volume?

Comment: I don't think this is supported in CentOS 5. You can do it in CentOS 6, though. And it's past time to upgrade anyway.

Comment: @Lars - it exactly that I want to do, but I need HVM CentOS5  image for this...

Comment: @Michael - do you mean CentOS5 doesn't support HVM?

Comment: This worked for me on Fedora PV to HVM. 

http://serverfault.com/a/617371/182827

Answer (score 0):

I found CentOS 5 HVM AMI in one of AWS regions and converted my image using method similar to 
http://www.nixhat.com/2014/01/migrate-aws-pv-to-hvm-instance, i.e. by cloning my "/" to HVM AMI.