# Amazon EC2: How to convert an existing PV AMI to HVM - CentOS - Wont boot

Tags: centos, pv, hvm

I've now tried every guide I've found on Google, some are posts on this forum. The instances always end up not booting with every guide/method I've tried. Probably spent about 4 days trying out different guides. I follow them to the greatest detail, never any errors. Only issue is when I'm done with the guides the instance wont boot. There is nothing logged inside "Get System Log".

I suspect that some special configuration has to be done to the bootloader that I'm not aware of.

These are the best guides that I've tried, none of them worked either:

[Create an AWS HVM Linux AMI from an Existing Paravirtual Linux AMI](https://serverfault.com/questions/439976/create-an-aws-hvm-linux-ami-from-an-existing-paravirtual-linux-ami)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427527/amazon-ec2-how-to-convert-an-existing-pv-ami-to-hvm-centos

https://www.caseylabs.com/convert-a-centos-pv-paravirtual-instance-to-hvm/

Ask me if there is any information you need me to provide, I'll do my best.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sincerely,
André

Comment: Nobody has any kind of recommendation or pointers toward what the issue possibly could be? It surprises me that Amazon itself has no documentation into this subject, from what I'm aware of.