# Convert AWS EC2 AMI from PV to HVM

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, pv, hvm

I'm trying to convert EC2 AMI from PV to HVM (To use some new instance_types). I did some actions as [@tolgamorf said here](https://serverfault.com/questions/439976/create-an-aws-hvm-linux-ami-from-an-existing-paravirtual-linux-ami/678867#_=_). Instance started and work.
But sometime, there 're some logs in /var/log/messages as:

> Dec 22 16:47:56  modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.4.23-31.54.amzn1.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory

What is the matter with that instance. Pls help (). It seems kernel of my old AMI is different with new HVM instance.