# No instances available for AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an old app running on EC2 classic box, and need to migrate it to a VPC. The old instance type is m1.small (Intel arch). I created an AMI for the server running the app, and tried to launch a new instance from it.

It only showed t1.micro and c3.large as available instance types. Everything else is grayed out.

I copied the AMI to the Ohio region and got no instance types available at all.

Is this a temporary capacity issue, or is there something wrong with my AMI that it won't run on a newer instance type?

Comment: m1.small is 1.7GB 1CPU instance. But m1 is not supported anymore (AFAIK). The closest is t2.small

Comment: Wow, Classic EC2 still works?! It may be something to do with HVM vs PV images - you may be on the old type. I suggest you follow an AWS guide or documentation such as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate.html

Comment: @Tim Yes, that was it. There just aren't that many instances available that support PV images. Thank you.

Comment: Please put an answer into your question how you resolved that. I assume you found an instance that supports PV images? I suggest you convert over to HVM, though I have no idea how to do that myself. Search will find a way if it's possible, otherwise it may be a rebuild.

Comment: @Tim There's really no resolution. If you have a PV image, you have to use one of the few available instance types, otherwise you have to create a new image from scratch, that is, start with a clean machine with a recent OS and reinstall all software.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your PV based image to HVM. There's a guide on [this page](https://sysadminxpert.com/how-to-convert-ec2-instance-pv-to-hvm-virtualization-type/), or you can look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/439976/create-an-aws-hvm-linux-ami-from-an-existing-paravirtual-linux-ami).

In short the general steps (look at the links rather than using this):

- Register the EC2 image (see the command below)
- Create a new HVM instance
- Attach disk images
- Launch the server

[AWS CLI Command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/register-image.html)

```
aws ec2 register-image --virtualization-type hvm
```

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/register-image.html